# Convert CURL to $.Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, curl, spotify

I'm using the spotify API and the sample code gave me a curl request to play around with. I tried to convert it into an ajax request but I'm having some trouble.

The curl code:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/12166097089/playlists" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <super long encryption string>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"name\":\"NewPlaylist\",\"public\":false}"
```

My attempted AJAX:

```
function create_playlist(user, hash) {
    xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + user + '/playlists',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '<same super long string>');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en_US');
        },
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            "name":"Temp Playlist",
            "public": false
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("it failed");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does the ajax return ?

Comment: It's supposed to return a JSON object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to stringify the data if sending as `application/json`. $.ajax won't do that for you

```
var dataObj = {
        "name":"Temp Playlist",
        "public": false
    }

$.ajax({
   ......
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("it failed");
    }
});
```

Also no need to create a `new XMLHttpRequest()`. That's what `$.ajax` is already doing

Comment: If I dont need the XMLHttpRequest, how do I send an authorization header?

Comment: same way you are doing it...the `xhr` argument in `beforeSend` is not the same object you created before `$ajax`. That function creates a closure. There is also a `headers` option in api

Comment: Never mind, you're right, I dont need the object I can just use the xhr! Thank you so much. It worked!